# Trying to assign nsdictionary to my nsarray but app crashes everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to assign my NSDictionary to my NSArray but app Crashes everytime here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i< myMutableArray.count; i++) {
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_name], @"hotelname",
                    [PriceArray objectAtIndex:i], @"startingfrom",
                    [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_city],@"city",
                    [DistanceArray objectAtIndex:i],@"distance",
                    [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_image],@"imagesnames",
                    [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_stars],@"numberofstars",
                    @"45.5016889",@"hotelLat",
                    @"-73.567256",@"hotelLong", nil];
    }

    NSArray *myArray = @[@{[dict allKeys] : [dict allValues]}];
```

and here is when i am passing data

```
BookATableController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bookatable"];
        BookATableController.myMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.rssOutputData];/// Passing Data
        BookATableController.PriceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:rssHotelPrice];/// Passing Data
        BookATableController.DistanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:rssHotelDistance];/// Passing
        [self.view addSubview:BookATableController.view];
        [self addChildViewController:BookATableController];
        [BookATableController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: I tried a simplified example, and didn't get a crash.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19f0e4490'

Comment: The crash must be somewhere else, then.  You aren't calling `length` in the posted code.

Comment: still getting the same error on crash. am i passing dictionary to nsarray the right way??

Comment: Your code logic doesn't seem to be right. A new dictionary is instantiated, but when _myMutableArray_ is looped through, it is reassigning _dict_ to a new value each time. _myArray_ is then being instantiated with one value which is the final _dict_. What is the intended behaviour?

Comment: This code does not crash.  You aren't posting the line which crashes.

Comment: `@{[dict allKeys] : [dict allValues]}` what is that?

Comment: Why not `@[dict]`?

Comment: assigning all the keys and their values to a nsarray!

Comment: that is my NSDictionary

Comment: Just use, breakpoint and step in and check each object,  you will find out the issue.

Comment: i have just checked app is crashing on this line "dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:..." and it is showing "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x401cccc.....so on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dictionary wouldn't work because your keys in the current state are not unique. Two suggestions for possible solutions,

1) I think the best is to create a Hotel object with the properties you want to store and initialize those objects in your for loop. I can give you an example if you would like one.

2) If you want to use the dictionary, you could do something like I've listed below, although there are probably many other variations you could try.

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfHotels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // 5 is random, you can use the count from 'myMutableArray'
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {

        NSArray *columnNames = @[@"hotelname",
                               @"startingfrom",
                               @"city",
                               @"distance",
                               @"imagesnames",
                               @"numberofstars",
                               @"hotelLat",
                               @"hotelLong"];

      NSArray *values = @[[[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_name],
                          [PriceArray objectAtIndex:i],
                          [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_city],
                          [DistanceArray objectAtIndex:i],
                          [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_image],
                          [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_stars],
                          @"45.5016889",
                          @"-73.567256"];

      [arrayOfHotels addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:columnNames forKeys:values]];
   }
```

Comment: so how can i use arrayOfHotels as a NSArray?

Comment: arrayOfHotels is an array of dictionarys, so [arrayOfHotels objectAtIndex:0] would return a dictionary with all the details for one of your hotels. How do you want to use the result?

Comment: after this change i am getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19f0e4490'

Comment: i nslog all the incoming values and the are all there not a single one is null!

Comment: strange, I tested the 'values' array with dummy values and it worked, maybe try the same put 8 random strings in 'values' and try again, e.g. @[@"1", @"2",...]; If could maybe show me the log values for PriceArray, DistanceArray and myMutableArray.